# IIS 7.5 doesn't open aspx, html pages

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have two ASP.NET sites on my IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008 R2)

First one works perfect, it opens default.aspx page any other aspx pages as well as html, but second site doesn't open neither .aspx nor .html links, so for example if I try to open http://mysite.com/Default.aspx url, it just shows an empty page without any content or any error.

What it could be?
Thanks.

Comment: Is ASP.NET configured for that site, correct modules? Are those 2 separate sites or 2webs under one site?

Comment: Those are two separated sites on the same server. What do you mean correct modules?

Comment: It seems to me that the browser may be displaying the html that is there; meaning that it's displaying the html, but nothing is visible. Can you view source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, many things can be broken.

Few tips:

- Start Chrome, Firefox (with Firebug addon) or Fiddler or any other http proxy and check what the server is sending - is it HTTP 200, 404, something else?
- check IIS logs c:\inetpub\logs\Logfiles\w3svc
- check EventLog
- compare httpmodules in working website with those of the website which is not working
- ensure correct app pool with correct .net version is set for site
- try to convert website to webapp
- if all fails, delete website and create it from scratch. If it works it may suggest that IIS metabase was damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround that I suggest:

Open the "hosts" file using Notepad in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

then add

127.0.0.1  YourWebsite

Next, try to add binding to a site as suggested here at (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

I hope it helps you.